# C++ template member variable in templatized class has incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

I have code similar to the following in a header file:

```
template<class A>
class List {
  private:
    QVector<A> _list;
};
```

where QVector is the standard QT container.

When I try to make a variable of type List as a member variable in another header file like this:

```
class Model {
  private:
    List<int *> the_list;
};
```

I get the following error:

```
In instantiation of 'List<int *>':
instantiated from here
error: 'List<A>::_list' has incomplete type
```

Basically, I want a custom list that is templatized that uses an internal QVector to store the data items.

I assume that my syntax is a little off, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're including the first header from the second?  Might be worth running just the preprocessor stage e.g. "gcc -E" to check things are as they appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have `#include`d the header file for `QVector` before your declaration of `class List { }`. If you omit it then `QVector` is an undefined type but because `List` is a templated class the compiler doesn't omit an error message until you instantiate `List` for the first time.

```
#include <QVector>

template<class A>
class List {
  private:
    QVector<A> _list;
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was the problem.  I must need more caffeine if I spent several hours on a missing #include :).

Comment: Note, many compilers *will* print an error for this, and even if QVector were defined between this declaration and the instantiation, it is still an error.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, looks like `QVector` was *forward declared*, so the compiler really is disallowed from erroring out early without instantiation of `List<T>`.